# Find duplicate folder names and ignore further subdirectory matches

Tags: bash

I have a data directory where duplicate folders have been created at various hierarchy levels. I want to find these duplicates using case insensitive comparison. I also want to ignore further subdirectory matches for every match, so as to reduce the noise, since in my usecase directory names are quite unique and indicate that all subdirectories are also likely to be duplicates (basically a given folder and all its subfolders has been copied at various locations). In other words, if 2 directories match but their parents, while being in different paths, also match, just return the parents.

For example, if I have the following folders:

```
a/b/Dup1
a/b/dup1/ignore1
c/dup1/ignore1
```

I want the output to be something like:

```
'dup1' found in:
a/b/Dup1
a/b/dup1
c/dup1
```

Any other output that lists all the case-insensitive duplicates and their relative or absolute path is also acceptable (or even just the name of the duplicate directory, since it should be easy to list its locations from there).

Comment: Check the [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining `find`, `sort` and `uniq` tools to get desired result. This one liner should work:

`find yourstartingpath -type d -printf '%f\n' |sort -i |uniq -icd |while read c x;do echo "===== $x found $c times in =====";find yourstartingpath  -type d -iname "$x" -printf '%p\n';done`

This oneliner will not remove subdirectories from search, but I believe it would be hard to do so with only bash core utilities. If it is necessary, depending on your system probably it would be better to write program in either perl or python to get what you need. Eventually you may restrict your results to folders, which have some common subdirectories, ie. using following oneliner:

`find yourstartingpath -type d -printf '%P\n'  |awk -F/ -v OFS='/'  'NF>=4 {print $(NF-1),$NF}' |sort -i |uniq -id |while read x;do echo "======= $x "; find yourstartingpath -type d -ipath "*$x";done`

but it will remove Dup1 folder from your example (because it does not have ignore1 subfolder).